# Enviar varios datos a PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, base-de-datos, web

Busco pasar algunos datos a un php para que desde él se haga actualización a una base de datos, lo estoy tratando de hacer así, pero recibo error. ¿Cuál sería la forma correta?

```
        function editarCamiseta(idcamiseta) {
            var nuevoPrecio = document.getElementById("nuevoPrecio").value;
            var nuevoStock = document.getElementById("nuevoStock").value;
            var nuevoNombre = document.getElementById("nuevoNombre").value;
            if (confirm("¿Estas seguro de editar esta camiseta?")) {
                let url = "clases/editarCamiseta.php";
                let data = new FormData();
                data.append("idcamiseta", idcamiseta);
                data.append("nuevoPrecio", nuevoPrecio);
                data.append("nuevoStock", nuevoStock);
                data.append("nuevoNombre", nuevoNombre);                    

                fetch(url, {
                    method: "POST",
                    body: data,
                    mode: 'cors'
                })             
            }
        };
```

En php tengo esto

```
<?php
require("../Config/conexion.php");
require("../Config/config.php");

$id = $_POST['idcamiseta'];
$nPrecio = $_POST['nuevoPrecio'];
$nStock = $_POST['nuevoStock'];
$nNombre = $_POST['nuevoNombre'];


$db = new Conexion();
$con = $db->conectar();

$sql = $con->prepare("UPDATE Tienda.Camiseta SET Nombre = $nNombre, Stock = $nStock, Precio =  $nPrecio WHERE idcamiseta = $id");
$sql->execute();
?>
```

Cualquier ayuda me vendría bien, creo que la solución debe ser sencilla pero apenas empiezo con estos temas, agradezco si me pueden colaborar

Comment: Por favor, añade el error concreto que te da

Answer (score 0):

El único problema es que a la hora de actualizar, como he usado un formato para el precio, guardaba una coma en la variable y esta generaba error por no ser un valor totalmente númerico.

Comment: si deseas agregar informacion o detalles a tu pregunta solo basta con editarla, no usar el campo de respuestas, la seccion de respuestas es para responder a la pregunta.

Comment: Respondí la pregunta. Ya está solucionado el problema